# Convert string (looking like array) to multidimensional array

Tags: javascript

I have a string: 
`[[-3.9,-160.1,34.7],[-0.4,16.3,18.0],[236,236,231],'SMTH 123',35]`

How I can convert it to a multidimensional array?

Comment: If you have written code for this that you can't get to work, then you have come to the right place. Just add your code (or the relevant parts) to the question, because without that we cannot help. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Do explain what your desired output should look like....

Comment: you can use `json_decode` if you're programming in PHP.

Comment: if the string comes from a trusted, non-user input related source you can use `eval()`

Comment: why are strings quoted with single quotes? if with double, you could use `JSON.parse`.

Comment: regex for the square brackets and then explode the subgroup matches etc... Just try something first.

Comment: Where is this string coming from? Do you have control over how it is generated?

Comment: You cannot.  With unreliable data like this, any attempt to regex is would result in unmanageable code.  You need to push back to the producer or make huge assumptions about the syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `JSON.parse()` to convert a string into an object, assuming it's valid JSON to begin with.  Your data has strings delimited by single quotes, which is not valid JSON.  If you replace them with double quotes then it will work...

```js
var s = "[[-3.9,-160.1,34.7],[-0.4,16.3,18.0],[236,236,231],'SMTH 123',35]";
var ar = JSON.parse(s.split("'").join("\""));
console.log(ar);
```

Comment: When you do JSON.parse remember to wrap it with try/catch - otherwise your script will end up with error.

Comment: @NetRat - this answer is for this specific question.  If there are any changes in the the data that would not work with `JSON.parse()` then this answer is not relevant.  Also, try/catch should be used about as often as eval.  You should never need it.

Comment: What about when `var s = ["it's complicated"]`? In this case replacing the single quote to a double quote will break a perfectly a valid JSON string.

Comment: @ElianEbbing See the comment above yours.

Answer (score 0):

How about doing something like this:

```
function stringToObject(data) {
    var converted = {};
    try {
        converted = JSON.parse(data);
    } catch(err) {
        console.log('Provided data is not valid', err);
    }
    return converted;
}

console.log(stringToObject('[[-3.9,-160.1,34.7],[-0.4,16.3,18.0],[236,236,231],"SMTH 123",35]'));
console.log(stringToObject('[[-3.9,-160.1,34.7],[-0.4,16.3,18.0],[236,236,231')); // invalid string
```

Notice that I have changed ' into " in my sample if that is a problem you may take a look at conversion done in another answer for that question.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming JQuery is also okay:

```
var arr = $.parseJSON('[[-3.9,-160.1,34.7],[-0.4,16.3,18.0],[236,236,231],'SMTH 123',35]')
```